# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in adapter

Tags: java, android

I want to list the JSON data received with this adapter, however am getting an error that says that he is not managing to find the view, The error I get in the log is "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view must not be null"

```
  public class categoriaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<categoriaModel> categoriaModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public categoriaAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<categoriaModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        categoriaModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;




        if (convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder.imgCategoria = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            holder.catTitulo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMovie);
            holder.catDesc = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTagline);
            holder.catID = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvYear);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(categoriaModelList.get(position).getImage(), holder.imgCategoria, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });



        holder.catTitulo.setText(categoriaModelList.get(position).getNome());
        holder.catDesc.setText(categoriaModelList.get(position).getDescricacao());
        holder.catID.setText(categoriaModelList.get(position).getIdeCategoria());



        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imgCategoria;
        TextView catTitulo;
        TextView catDesc;
        TextView catID;
    }
}
```

And my 
[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCJZw.png)

Comment: Are you sure your convertView is not null?

Comment: Yes, I had taken the test with Log.v, and convertView is null

Comment: try to change convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null); to convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

Comment: I tried, but the same error ...

Comment: What is line 70 of `ViewAware` class?

Comment: DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true).build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); // Do it on Application start

Comment: Check if `ImageView imgCategoria` is null..

Comment: on class "ViewHolder" or after: holder.imgCategoria = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);

Comment: before `ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage` check if `imgCategoria` is null..

Comment: And also add `imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(parent.getContext()));` before the function `displayImage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your layout(xml) and see if R.id.ivIcon is an imageView or if it is present in the `resource` layout. Make sure `imgCategoria` is not null and is properly initialised before calling `displayImage`.

Also initialize ImageLoader configuration. i.e.

```
 ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
 ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(categoriaModelList.get(position).getImage(), holder.imgCategoria, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you included the right item layout. I had same issue turns out I was using item layout of different activity. And I had duplicated the adapter code.